# Loopback soap connector not populating the model with the service methods

Tags: web-services, soap, loopbackjs

I am having trouble consuming soap web service using loopback-connector-soap. I followed the instructions [from github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-soap) and [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/SOAP+connector).

I am able to consume the web service provided in the example but when I replace it with my wsdl it doesn't work. There are no errors after connecting but after creating the model, calling any method exposed by the web service fails with the error message

> Object function ModelConstructor(data, options) { if (!(this instanceof ModelConstructor)) { return new ModelConstructor(data, options); } if (ModelClass.settings.unresolved) { throw new Error('Model ' + ModelClass.modelName + ' is not defined.'); } ModelBaseClass.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'GetAgentBalance'

My code snippet is as shown below

```
var api = {};    
var ds = loopback.createDataSource('soap', {
        connector: 'loopback-connector-soap',
        remotingEnabled: true,
        wsdl: 'https://jambopay.com/agencyservices?WSDL',// The url to WSDL
        wsdl_options: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            strictSSL: false,
            requestCert: true,
        }
    });

    // Unfortunately, the methods from the connector are mixed in asynchronously
    // This is a hack to wait for the methods to be injected

ds.once('connected', function () {
    // Create the model     
    var service = ds.createModel('AgencyService', {});

    api.getBalance = function (callback) {
        //Displays the parsed WSDL 
        console.log(ds.connector);
        var timestamp = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var pass = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(apiUsername + timestamp + apiKey).digest("hex");
        //GetAgentBalance is a method in the web service.
        service.GetAgentBalance({ username: apiUsername, timestamp: timestamp, pass: pass }, function (err, response) {
            var result = (!err && response.Balance) ? response.Balance : null;
            callback(err, result);
        });

    }
});

module.exports = api;
```

The `console.log(ds.connector)` displays the wsdl content plus a flag `parsed:true` meaning it was parsed successfully. 
Kindly help me figure out why the model is not being populated with the methods from the web service which is preventing the consumption of the web service. Please note that this web service works fine in ASP.NET,Java as well as PHP and I guess several other languages and frameworks. I'm stuck at this point and your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this code in your application? There are a couple things wrong, first of which is that the `service` variable is a constructor function for a model, not the current instance of a model. You would want to place the `getBalance` method definition inside the model file for `AgencyService`.

Comment: Hello @jakerella. Thank you for the feedback. This code is in a file I'm exposing as a module in my application. However, if you look at the [Read Me usage instructions for loopback-connector-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-soap), the `service` variable is assigned to a model variable created from the datasource `ds`. The name passed to the `ds` doesn't really matter as I have tried with some other values like 'X' and worked just fine with other working wsdl. I have also tried this with node-soap but it still fails with my wsdl. I can't figure out why!

Comment: Dang... Well, I looked at the wsdl and didn't see anything right away. Not sure I can be of more help. Sorry!! And good luck.

Comment: Well, that is sad but thanks anyway for your willingness to assist.

Comment: I finally got the web service working by using a different module, `foam`. [Foam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foam) is a simple soap client that  instead of discovering the WSDL like `soap` and `loopback-connector-soap`, it  just posts directly the data to the endpoint. Works like a charm! @jakerella